# How to create nested directory with a specified permission bit for each of the parents directory created?

Tags: linux, permissions

The following isn't working as expected, and I am trying to understand if this is a bug or is there a hidden configuration in my linux machine that prevented it to create the folder with the correct permission. As a last resort, I could always fallback to creating the folder one by one, but I hope it doesn't come to this.

Here's what I do:

```
mkdir -m777 /familytree
mkdir -m755 -p /familytree/great-grandparent/grandparent/parent/myself/
```

This is what I got:

```
$ namei -m /familytree/great-grandparent/grandparent/parent/myself/

dr-xr-xr-x /
drwxrwxrwx familytree
drwx------ great-grandparent
drwx------ grandparent
drwx------ parent
drwxr-xr-x myself
```

Here's what I expected:

```
   $ namei -m /familytree/great-grandparent/grandparent/parent/myself/

dr-xr-xr-x /
drwxrwxrwx familytree
drwxr-xr-x great-grandparent
drwxr-xr-x grandparent
drwxr-xr-x parent
drwxr-xr-x myself
```

Answer (score 0):

This depends on your `umask`. In my Kubuntu I got different results probably because my `umask` is different than yours.

The following should work (note I use relative paths, so one can test the code in an arbitrary directory; `cd` to the directory first):

```bsh
mkdir -m777 familytree
( umask 022
  mkdir -p familytree/great-grandparent/grandparent/parent/myself/
)
```

(The point of the subshell is to leave the `umask` of the main shell intact.)

The result:

```
drwxrwxrwx familytree
drwxr-xr-x great-grandparent
drwxr-xr-x grandparent
drwxr-xr-x parent
drwxr-xr-x myself
```

To learn how `umask` works see [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/287281/108618).

Note I did not use `-m` with the second `mkdir`. If I used it, I could get different permissions for the final directory than for "intermediate" ones, similarly to what you got. The difference is now you know how to control the permissions of "intermediate" directories. Example:

```bsh
rm -r familytree
mkdir -m777 familytree
( umask 027
  mkdir -m700 -p familytree/great-grandparent/grandparent/parent/myself/
)
```

New result:

```
drwxrwxrwx familytree
drwxr-x--- great-grandparent
drwxr-x--- grandparent
drwxr-x--- parent
drwx------ myself
```